# create a new column with multiple values based on multiple conditions in multiple columns

Tags: python, dataframe, multiple-columns, multiple-conditions

I am still really new and try to rewrite all my SQL codes with Python. I'd like to write a python script based on the SQL codes below:

```
when lower(level2_desc) = "childrens" then "CHW"
when lower(level3_desc) like '%bags%' then "Bags"
when lower(level3_desc) like '%shoes%' then "Shoes"
when lower(level3_desc) = "scarves" then "Scarves"
when lower(level4_desc) like '%sm lthr goods%' then "SLG"
when lower(level2_desc) like '%accessories%' then "Small Acc"
when lower(level2_desc) not in ("accessories", "childrens") and lower(level3_desc) like '%outerwear%' and lower(level4_desc) like "%rainwear%" then "RW"
when lower(level2_desc) not in ("accessories", "childrens") and lower(level3_desc) like '%outerwear%' and lower(level4_desc) not like '%rainwear%' then "OTW"
when lower(level2_desc) not in ("accessories", "childrens") and lower(level3_desc) not like "%outerwear%" then "RTW"
```

I have tried lambda, but it will overlap the values.

```
df['cat'] = df[['level2_desc']].apply(lambda x: 'CHW' if 'CHILDREN' in x else x, axis=1)
df['cat'] = df[['level3_desc']].apply(lambda x: '%bags%' if 'BAGS' in x else x, axis=1)
```

Also tried self-defined function, but never went through (no errors).

```
df['cat'] = ""

def cat(value):
  if df['level2_desc'] == "CHILDREN":
    df['cat'] == "CHILDREN"
  if df['level3_desc'] == "%BAGS%":
    df['cat'] == "bags"
    
df
```

Expected outcome is:
[Expected outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rHXQi.png)

Comment: Sorry, you want to do this `df['cat'] = 'CHILDREN'`, so set the value equal to `'CHILDREN` or do `df['cat'] == "CHILDREN"`? If the latter, how is that supposed to let you achieve you expected outcome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to filter your `pd.dataframe` based on certain condition and then change the value inside the cell, only of the rows which respect the condition imposed on another column, you can do this:
In your case

```
df['cat'] = np.nan # create an empty column
df.loc[df['level2_desc'] == "CHILDREN", 'cat'] = "CHILDREN"
df.loc[df['level3_desc'] == "%BAGS%", 'cat'] = 'bags'
```